# Verbatim Match with sed

Tags: sed

I have a list of pairs of URLs - I want to find all occurrences of the first element of the pair and replace them with the second. I'm trying to use sed for this but sed escapes characters in my URL. Is there a way to make sed find these URLs (without changing my pairs)?

Here's my code:

```
while read -r NAME
do
    ARG1=`echo "$NAME" | awk '{print $1}'`
    ARG2=`echo "$NAME" | awk '{print $2}'`
    echo "$ARG1"
    echo "$ARG2"
    sed -i "s@$ARG1@$ARG2@g" file
done < pagetable
```

pagetable has the pairs of URLS, and I'm doing the find and replace in 'file'. Since my URLs have special characters, sed isn't interpreting them verbatim.

Comment: could you give an example url that was not replaced as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the metacharacters in the search pattern (`\` `*` `^` `$` `.` `/`) *and in the replacement string* (`&` `/`) before invoking `sed`. This assumes that the script is run by Bash.

```
ARG1="${ARG1//\\/\\\\}"
ARG1="${ARG1//\*/\\\*}"
ARG1="${ARG1//\//\\/}"
for mc in \^ \$ \.; do ARG1="${ARG1//$mc/\\$mc}"; done
ARG2="${ARG2//\\/\\\\}"
ARG2="${ARG2//\//\\/}"
ARG2="${ARG2//&/\\&}"
sed -i "s/$ARG1/$ARG2/g" file
```